# Where to write files on disk from my Sandbox app without User interaction?

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesystems, save, sandbox

I have designed an app for MacOSX. Its function is to manipulate PDf files. 
First the user would import files "in" the app. 
After manipulating the files, the files are saved and kept in the library.

Actually, it is exactly the concept of Library of iTunes. You have files inside and you don't bother where they are located. It is better if the user do not have to select any folder in the system.

My question is : Where do I write my files on the disk?

I know I have to write it in a specific place but I can't figure out where. I tried in the App Bundle but I read somewhere we can not with sandboxing and indeed it didn't work.

I know I can write my preferences in my NSUserDefaults. Can I write any files there?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the files in the application support directory. Use `NSFileManager` to locate it as described here: [URLsForDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:)

And read the [sandbox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW6) for further details.